# Text was truncated or one or more characters from Excel Source?

Tags: excel, sql-server-2008, ssis

When I am trying to do package from Excel source i got the below message:

```
Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page When importing from Excel file
```

I read some comments in Google and tried to change `Registry Editot 'Typeguessrows to 0` and also change connection string property to `IMEX=1;` still I am getting same problem 
what to do? any suggestions...thanks

Comment: What datatype is set in the connection manager for the affected column? Consider changing it to Unicode (W_STR).

Comment: Brian O''Byrne, thanks for the reply ..I have done that but still same problem

Comment: Check to make sure that the length of the column is Excel is not greater than length of column in table.